# How to change the colour of the lines in density plot produced from sm.density.compare( ) in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have produced a figure with 4 density plots as shown below, using sm.density.compare in R:

How can I change the colour of the lines? Also of interest is how I can change the type of the line? i.e. dotted, solid

[image: density plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same parameters as in other base plotting functions - `col=` for the colors and `lty=` for the line types.

```
library(sm)    
y <- rnorm(100)
g <- rep(1:2, rep(50,2))
sm.density.compare(y, g,col=c("blue","black"),lty=c(4,6))
```

[image]